# shortcut for changing the editor font size in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any shortcut for changing the font size in Oracle SQL Developer? like we have Ctrl+Mouse Wheel in SQL Server. I searched everywhere but I could not find anything. Please help if someone know.

Comment: This is the wrong forum, please check out https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 38):

Yes, there is a way to increase or decrease the font size.

Please follow the steps below:

1. Click Tools, select Preferences.
2. Click on Code Editor.
3. Click Fonts.
4. Set the size in the Font Size drop-down.

Comment: I guess some people come here from Google that upvote this answer. However, it does not answer OP‘s question as this is not a shortcut.

Answer (score 12):

The method outlined in this post worked for me on Windows 10. (Note that this will edit the UI Font and for me it was necessary to do the second part of this to change the Editor font using the Tools -> Preferences -> Code Editor -> Fonts page):

https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/12/how-to-change-the-ui-font-size-for-oracle-sql-developer/

Modify the FontSize properties in this file (your path will differ a bit):
C:\Users\jdsmith\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system4.1.0.13.75\o.sqldeveloper\ide.properties

and (from the comments)

Right Click on sqldeveloper.exe icon and select Properties.

Go to the Compatibility tab:

- Click the "Change high DPI settings
- Check the option of Override high DPI scaling behavior
- Select “System” in drop down below
- Apply
- Re-Launch the application

Comment: that's to change the UI font, not the Editor font

Comment: Good point @thatjeffsmith, although I found it was necessary to do this for the editor font changes to work. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

By default there are no keyboard shortcuts for those actions. However, you can set some yourself. Here's how:

- open "Preferences" (you'll find it in the "Tools" menu).
- scroll the left hand side down until you find "Shortcut keys"; click it
- on a top of the right hand side you'll see the "Search" field - put "font"
  in there; "Decrease" and "Increase Font Size" will automatically
  appear
- set them to any shortcut you find appropriate

Comment: I tried that but those shortcut keys don't work for changing the font size. Thank you though.

Comment: Oh, yes - I tried it myself (unfortunately, just now, instead of yesterday). Those shortcuts DO work, but not in Editor - instead, they are used to increase or decrease font size in SQL Developer  **Help** (you know, the one that opens when you press F1). That's what "Category" in "Shortcut keys" means. My bad, should have done it earlier. Sorry. Huh, it appears that you can't do it, after all. However, you can set fixed Editor font size, also in "Preferences".

Comment: Yes, now I am using the fixed size font in Editor. Thanks a lot @Littlefoot.

Answer (score 2):

To increase or decrease the font size in Oracle SQL developer(Not a shortcut as per OP). Please follow the below steps.

-> Click Tools, select Preferences.

->Type "Font" in the search box on the top corner of the left side

->Select size in "Font Size" field on right hand side to increase or decrease font size.

Comment: this doesn't work plus the shortcut key manager is really weird.

Answer (score 1):

In case of MacBook, The Preferences will be available on the App Menu

i.e Oracle SQL Developer -> Preferences

or use Command +

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd> seems to work in SQLDeveloper 22.2.0.173.

Comment: This is a "thanks" for https://stackoverflow.com/a/54153565/7733418 isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

To use ctrl + scroll mouse, only work in plsql editor

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can change font in Sql Developer 11g
Please follow the below  steps
1.Click Tools
2.select Preferences.
3.Click on Code Editor.
4.Click Fonts.
5.select the font size form DropDown
6.slect the font Name from Dropdown

Answer (score -1):

1. Click on `ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER` if you are on a Mac
2. There will be a search bar and then you can search for fonts and the you can enlarge.

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).